# SAS How to add space in between a string?

Tags: sas

I want to generate value for a variable in this format X (XX).
eg: 7 (70)

I've the values in the variables N and PctN_01. SO tried
    value = cats(N," (",PctN_01,")");
But its not adding the space. I get the result 7(70). So what do I do?

Comment: Documentation for the `cats()` function: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1e21rr6al5m2nn19r1fat5qxwrt.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two 'cat' functions, `cats` and `catx` - catx concatenates with a delimiter...

```
value = catx(" ", N, cats("(", PctN_01, ")")) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a version of SAS prior to version 9 (catx not available) then you can do it along the lines of:

```
value = N || "(" || PctN_01 || ")";
```